# Boostrap4 carousel expands during the transition

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

In the below code snippet, the carousel pushes the container element on transition, moving the adjacent element (in cases where there is an adjacent element) with it.  What is the reason and how do you think this can be fixed so that at transition, the adjacent element is not moved.

Code for carousel:

```html
<html>
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>


<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">


 
 <div class="my-5 mx-3">
  

 

 <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade w-100 pointer-event" id="featured" data-ride="carousel">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
       <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="carousel-item active carousel-item-left">
          <img class="d-block  m-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/400/300" alt="Convoluted Excel ">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>Headache!</h3>
            <p> The current situation is nothing but headache! Clearly, simple is better than the complex situation at hand</p>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-next carousel-item-left">
          <img class="d-block m-auto " src="https://picsum.photos/id/600/400/300" alt="Excel Prone to errors">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>SpreadSheet Headache!</h3>
            <p> The first reason why we are so awesome. Another reason why we are so awesome </p>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block m-auto " src="https://picsum.photos/id/700/400/300" alt="Clear dashboard">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>Web-based Solution</h3>
            <p>The first reason why we are so awesome. Another reason why we are so awesome. Yet another reason!</p>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>

   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
       </span>
   </a>

       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
       <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
           <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
       </span>
      </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="fancy-layout py-2 px-2 my-5 mx-3">


 
  <div class="Bacground-triangleSVG"></div>
   <h2 class="fancy-text">Sign up for a free one-month trial</h2>
  <div class="flex-card-horizontal">
   <div class="vertical col-md-8">

    
     <form action="" method="post" id="signUpForm"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="CTbqoQdjWoVXylqXbNL9bUOJurLZ0aTAOAna4j6fBRojFKQiOLcWz7">
      
      <div class="form-group">
       

<div id="div_id_email" class="form-group"> <label for="id_email" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Email<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="email" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_email"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_password1" class="form-group"> <label for="id_password1" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Password<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="password" name="password1" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_password1"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_password2" class="form-group"> <label for="id_password2" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Password Confirmation<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="password" name="password2" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_password2"> </div> </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="signup_button" disabled="">Sign Up <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></button>
      </div>

     </form>

    
   </div>

   
   <div class="vertical"> 
    <div class="header pt-5" id="feedback"> </div>
    <div class="header pt-5">Password hint </div>

          <div class="horizontal text-left">
     <span class="line" id="condition1"></span>
     <span class="line" id="condition2"></span>
     <span class="line" id="condition3"></span>

     
    </div>
    <div class="text-left pb-5">
      <ul>
       <li class="no-border pt-3"><span class="h4"></span><span class="h5" id="condition1Message">At least 6 characters</span></li>
       <li class="no-border pt-3"><span class="h4"></span><span class="h5" id="condition2Message">At least one uppercase letter</span></li>
       <li class="no-border pb-3"><span class="h4"></span><span class="h5" id="condition3Message">At least one number </span></li>
       

      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>  
     
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**
For some reason, the snippet does not show the carousel captions.  Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/esonemail/qm23wf0r/36/)